# Disabling copy/paste in Windows/Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have 3 computers in my department with Windows 10. Those computers are used by several people to report the material consumed. They report the information by entering into a website (MES system) via Chrome browser.

Over the last 10 years people are used to open the 'inventory report' and copy/paste the information from there to the page where it requests what material they have used.

The problem I have is that sometimes they believe they have picked a pallet with product A but they have picked by mistake pallet with product B. Each pallet has barcode information with the product and they have barcode scanners.

However as it is faster copy/pasting form the report rather than using the scanner, they hardly ever use it.

And the consequence is that from time to time we get complains from customers with the wrong product being delivered.

**How can I disable copy/paste (right clic copy/paste) and Ctrl Ctrl V?** As I said we use Chrome browser and Windows.

PS: I have no access to the website code, so a solution cannot be modifying the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could add some code to every webpage with Tampermonkey.
https://www.makeuseof.com/disable-text-selection-cut-copy-paste-right-click-on-web-page/

And you could use AutoHotKey or something similar to disable those key combinations.

But the easiest solution is probably a script (e.g. with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)) that keeps emptying the clipboard.

```
#include <Misc.au3>

_Singleton("dontcopythatfloppysir")

Opt ("WinTitleMatchMode", 4)
Opt("TrayIconHide", 1) ;hide tray menu icon

While 1
    ClipPut("")
    Sleep(1)
WEnd
```

That way, if they copy something, it gets removed from the clipboard before they get a chance to paste it.

Compile it with an important-sounding name and then add it to `shell:startup`

Comment: thanks, I will try that!